# how to access xhtml file from jar file

Tags: jsf-2, hyperlink, jar, facelets

I am working with jsf 2.0 project. i want to access xhtml file from jar file. in jar file i putted three files first.html, second.xhtml, h1.jpg. i can access jpg and html file from jar using following url.

```
<h:graphicImage url="#{resource['h1.jpg']}"/> 
<h:outputLink value="#{resource['first.html']}">
           <h:outputText value="OutputLink"/>
</h:outputLink>}
```

but i cant access xhtml from jar using following urls.

```
<h:outputLink value="#{resource['second.xhtml']}">
           <h:outputText value="OutputLink"/>
</h:outputLink>

<h:outputLink value="#{resource['second.jsf']}">
           <h:outputText value="OutputLink"/>
</h:outputLink>}
```

it is giving source not found error.

my jar structure is jar:META-INF/resources

Answer (score 0):

A XHTML (Facelet) file is not a resource. Just reference it the usual way.

```
<h:outputLink value="second.xhtml">OutputLink</h:outputLink>
```

or

```
<h:link value="OutputLink" outcome="second" />
```

Comment: Thanks for Reply. But I already tried that. it is not working. please if you have any other idea.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same issue for the past few days.  I tried a bunch of things and what finally worked for me was changing the top of my web.xml to:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    version="3.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">`

Hope that works for you.

Comment: That's the default/standard declaration. What mistake did you made before that you got the problem?

Comment: I was using version 2.5 and when I switched the declaration to 3.0 I was able to access the xhtml files that were in the meta-inf folder of the other jars.  The other things I tried were just tinkering around like creating a custom resolver (which shouldn't be needed for jsf 2) and putting a faces-config in the meta-inf folder of the jars.

Comment: Which JSF impl/version were you using? JSF 2.0 supports Servlet 2.5, but JSF 2.1 requires a minimum of Servlet 3.0.

Comment: For my project I was trying to get a skeleton project running with jsf 2, spring 3 and primefaces.  After I couldnt get the external jar thing working with the original project I had I decided to use spring roo. I went through this tutorial [link](http://java.dzone.com/articles/jsf-20-spring-roo). And the project that resulted from that worked with xhtml files and resource files from external jars right away. So then I just took what I needed from that project and matched my current project to it's configurations.  Thats when I discovered the 2.5 to 3.0 problem